# Why do we produce so many sperm?

Tags: reproduction

So apparently we produce roughly 300 million sperm daily. Is there a reason why this is necessary? Wouldn't a much smaller (but still large) number be sufficient? Like, one million?

Comment: Can you add a source for this number?

Comment: @Chris it's something they just taught us in the biology class (I imagine it is also in the book http://www.amazon.com/Biological-Science-MasteringBiology-3rd-Edition/dp/0321543270). Google searches yield ranges from 80 to 250 million - either of these numbers serve the purpose of my question though. I don't really care how many are produced, but rather, what's the point of making so many.

Comment: The one winner out of millions is more special than the one out of two :)

Comment: so the question is, how does 300 million sperm cells are better than one? like, one sperm -- one egg?

Comment: @aaaaaa yeah exactly :D

Comment: It's interesting that you think 300 million is "so many" but 1 million is not. My point is, one's intuition for what is a "reasonable" number of things in nature is often a poor guide.

Comment: @Chelonian *"Wouldn't a much smaller (**but still large**) number be sufficient? Like, one million?"* I don't think I ever said one million is a small number. I said it is much smaller compared to 300 million. So the question is mostly about whether or not a much smaller amount would be sufficient.

Comment: One might guess that it is simply a hangover from fish doing external fertilization.  Evolution is not intelligent design: if something works, it tends to be conserved even if it is not 'perfect'.  To get to say 1 'sperm' fertilizing 1 egg, you'd have to back down a bunch of evolutionary paths, and take different branches...

Comment: @Voldemort Notice I didn't write that you said 1 million is a small number. I said that you didn't think it was "so many". Which was the case, wasn't it?

Comment: @Chelonian no, I never said that 1 million was not "so many". I said that it is much less than 300 million, but still large. So yes, I think that 1 million is still "so many", and the question is therefore "why not 1 million instead of 300 million? Both numbers are still massive"

Comment: @Voldemort Fair enough. My point about our intuition not being a good guide to what the numbers for things like this ought to be still seems applicable to human intuition generally; that is, why should 1 million, for example, be enough? Why not 24,500? The point is, the numbers are what they are, and maybe 300 million is the appropriate number (or maybe the system isn't optimized?).

Comment: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39612/why-are-so-many-spermatozoa-produced-when-only-one-of-them-fertilises-the-ovum/39618#39618

Answer (score 5):

The term you should look up is **sperm competition**, there is an introductory wikipedia article about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperm_competition), where you can get the basic picture and get some references to explore.

Simply said, males often compete with other males in the reproductive tract of the female, thus a higher number of sperm will lead to a higher chance of fertilizing the female in competition with other males - leading to an arms-race of the number of sperms a male eject into the female.

There is a lot more to it, of course, but I believe this well explains the most fundamental driver of why males generally produce and eject so many sperms.

Comment: If a male mates with the female, and then comes another male, wouldn't the first male be much more likely to succeed because he introduced the sperm beforehand? I imagine that just a few hours are a huge advantage, so I'm not sure why would one need so many millions of sperm anyway.

Comment: @Voldemort I think it's safe to say that any advantage of being first for a certain amount of time would be highly dependent on the nature of the species in question. But if the production of sperm is relatively cheap and the competition is relatively significant, I think it's easy to see that we might reach an arms-race here, even if the amount of sperm would not always have to be the most important factor.

Comment: @Voldemort And if we look at humans as an example, we are curiously unique in an unexpected way as our penises seem to [have evolved to displace semen of other males from the vagina](http://www.ehbonline.org/article/S1090-5138%2803%2900016-3/abstract), so sperm competition seems to be very real even in humans.

Comment: Great reference Alex, right on track. Also high production of sperm also has to do with male health and dominance. In the wild a more dominant healthy male will produce more sperm and healthier sperm. Females pick up on this and will want to mate with someone strong. I'm humans this characteristic is not as widely perceived but women will tend to be attracted to a male that seams strong because psychologically he can " protect her and their young" of course we have evolved to money being a statement of power and dominance thus this can also serve as competition. All in all it boils down to ove

Answer (score 2):

The answer, if you search [for](http://goaskalice.columbia.edu/why-does-it-take-millions-sperm-fertilize-egg) a [bit](http://scienceline.org/2008/06/ask-olson-sperm/), boils down to geometry. It takes X amount of sperm cells to successfully fertilize an egg. If you optimize delivery system (e.g. vagina geometry), you'll need less. In species where one male fertilize number of eggs (aka polygamy) and are able to have progeny from number of females, you need less cells in ejaculate to produce single child, because chances are higher with higher number of matings.

In humans it is quite often one male-one female relationship, so you have to bump number of cells in ejaculate so that mating season is fruitful.

Final point of real-life statistics:

> [Of the 300 million sperm ejaculated, only about 200 or so will survive to reach the egg cell and only one will succeed in fertilizing it.](http://www.pennmedicine.org/encyclopedia/em_DisplayAnimation.aspx?gcid=000120&ptid=17)

You need to beat these odds ($10^{-6}$) in order to reproduce. Why female reproductive organs are so restrictive? Probably because there is some link between male's overall fitness and number of sperm cells. Fit males (those that hunt better than others) are able to spend more energy for generating sperm, rather than "feeding" their own body. If they able to "feed" 300 million sperm cells, they probably will be able to feed a child.

Comment: Your theory seems to go straight against the sperm competition theory?

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious of the implied statistics here... If there were 300 million sperm, and 40 million reached the egg, still only 1 would fertilise it (*[except in rare cases](http://www.nature.com/news/2007/070326/full/news070326-1.html)*). Also you're relying on something like bodily system integrity to imply sperm count reflects general fitness. I'm not sure if something like this has been demonstrated. I'd be very interested if you could provide a citation for that line.